# Can't get the correct serial response between Raspberrypi 4 and Pico

Tags: python, pi-4, serial, uart, pi-pico

I'm trying to make a little connection between both my Raspberry pi 4 and my Pico.

Everything was ok until the pico suddenly stoped recieving what I'm sending from the Raspberrypi.

**Expected Outcome**
I should receive on my Pico the following binary, or at least the letters in binary one-by-one, as:

```
b'h'
b'e'
b'l'
b'l'
b'o'
```

**Actual Outcome**

```
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
b'\x00'
```

Here is the Pico code where I should receive the binary that says `b'hello'` byte-by-byte:

```
from machine import UART, Pin
uart1 = UART(0, 115200, timeout=1, tx=Pin(0), rx=Pin(1))

while True:
    byte = uart1.read(1) # this reads one byte at atime
    if not byte:
        continue
    if uart1.any() > 0:
        print(byte)
```

Here is the Raspberrypi code where I send the binary that says `b'hello'`:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
        '/dev/serial0',
        11520,
        timeout=1
    )

ser.write(b"hello") # this sends through the serial connection, in this case it's UART
```

Comment: Please EDIT your question and document the following commands.  `uart1.read(1)` and `ser.write(b"hello")`.  What are each of them meant to do according to the published documentation?

Comment: thanks for your comment, does this look better? @joan

Comment: That does not look like what the library author would have written.  Somewhere there should be a statement of what each function does.

Comment: @Meno-101 what is your specific question?

Comment: @Meno-101 did you verify the hardware?

Comment: yes I have just verified the hardware once again to be sure. I question is basically is why am I getting this result eventhough I had it working like 30 minutes before asking the question, I checked like everything and it's supposed to be right.

Comment: Right I knew it, it's the buadrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the Buadrate, I had it as 11520 while it should be 115200